# Symfony autowiring Event Listener

Tags: symfony

Symfony 4.2.2

To cache all responses in one controller, I'm using an event listener for the kernel.controller event. My Event listener needs a couple of services and info:

- EnityManagerInterface
- the controller being cached
- kernel cache folder

I have set this up like this:

```
namespace App\Listener;


use App\Controller\DataOutputController;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;

class CachedOutput{

    protected $cacheFolder;
    protected $em;
    protected $controller;
    public function __construct($cacheFolder, EntityManagerInterface $em, DataOutputController $controller )
    {
        $this->cacheFolder = $cacheFolder;
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->controller = $controller;
    }



    public function findCachedObject(FilterControllerEvent $event, $eventName, TraceableEventDispatcher $dispatcher

    ){
        $params      = $event->getRequest()->attributes->get('_route_params');

        $fileType = $this->em->getRepository('App:FileType')->find($params->get('fileType'));
        $dataSet = $this->controller->getDataSet($params->get('dataSetSearch')?:'latest', $fileType->getType());

        $cacheFile = $this->cacheFolder.'/output/DS'.$dataSet->getId().'-FT'.$fileType->getId().'.html';

        if (file_exists($cacheFile)){
            $fh = fopen($cacheFile,'r');
            return new Response(fpassthru($fh));
        }
    }



}



services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        public: true       # Allows optimizing the container by removing unused services; this also means
                            # fetching services directly from the container via $container->get() won't work.
                            # The best practice is to be explicit about your dependencies anyway.
        bind:
            $projectDir: '%kernel.project_dir%'
    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']


    controller.return_cached_output:
        class: App\Listener\CachedOutput
        arguments:
            $cacheFolder: "%kernel.cache_dir%"
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: findCachedObject }
```

However, I still get an error regarding the cache folder:

Cannot autowire service "App\Listener\CachedOutput": argument "$cacheFolder" of method "__construct()" has no type-hint, you should configure its value explicitly.

What am I missing?

Update:

Have tried to use alias for the service like this:

```
App\Listener\CachedOutput:
    public: false
    arguments:
        $cacheFolder: "%kernel.cache_dir%"
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: findCachedObject }

return_cached_output:
    alias: App\Listener\CachedOutput
    public: true
```

with no success

Comment: where is your listener in the project ?

Comment: App/Listener/Cached Output.php

Comment: where do you declare your listener as service ?

Comment: The whole services.yaml is in the question

Comment: It is a very common mistake.  Autowire tries to convert every class into a service.  When it finds your App\Listener\CachedOutput class it checks services.yaml for a service with an id of App\Listener\CachedOutput.  Does not find one and thus tries to create a new service.  Your existing service is irrelevant.  Just add an alias to services.yaml: "App\Listener\CachedOutput: controller.return_cached_output"  If possible, get rid of all your snake case service ids and just use the class names.

Comment: Off topic: Turn your listener into a [subscriber](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-subscriber) and you can get rid of the tags section.  Bind $cacheFolder in your _defaults section (like $projectDir) and you can get rid of the manual service definition completely.

Comment: @Cerad, i think i have this line in there already. If i remove the cache folder parameter, debugger stops in my service

Comment: Not according to the services.yaml you posted.  And the error message is exactly what you get when autowire cannot determine what to inject.  Update your question if something has changed.

Comment: @Cerad Please see updated question trying to use alias

Comment: You have something else going on.  Is this a fresh project or an upgrade from something earlier?  I took a new S4.2 project and just added the listener and a fake controller and everything works.  Off topic but injecting a controller into a listener does not make much sense.  You can pull the current controller from the event.  But again, having the controller in there is not going to impact autowire.

Comment: Ok, binding it from default works. Ill just leave it at that. It's acresh project

Comment: Also agree on the controller comment, just a helper function that is needed both in controller and caching listener could be moved to a service of course

Comment: If ou get bored sometime, try using "bin/console debug container Cached".  I suspect you will find two copies of your service with different id's.  Which could cause amusing side effects down the line.

Comment: Have just done, there is only one

Answer (score 1):

You need to type-hint in your `__construct(string $cacheFolder, ...)`

Comment: And that will do what?  How will autowire know which string to inject?